# React Render a Component in two places

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render a component in two places of the page.

```
<FavoriteIndicator
contact={contact}
>
```

If I copy the code above twice, I will create two instance of the component and each component has its own state. However, I only want to create one instance of the component and render it in two places of the page. Is it possible to do this in React?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you want to manage state within this or another parent component, not within the `FavoriteIndicator` component.  (Or perhaps globally with Redux.)

Comment: Yes, it's possible

Comment: Rendering a component twice is usually not a issue. Is there any specific reason not to render it twice?

Comment: You need to lift state up if you want to use the same state for `contact` in multiple components - https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need to manage state globally. There are many different ways to do this, but I'd suggest one of these options:

- Redux
- Context API
- Parent Component State

The simplest one might be to just put the state in the parent component, but for beginners it's a nice exercise to use reacts **Context API** with hooks. I wouldn't recommend learning redux for now, as it's probably overkill in this situation and far more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do, which I would not recommend is to use ReactDOM.createPortal:

```
const Page = () => {
  const bar = 'bar';
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ color: 'red'}} id="header" />
      <div>
        <Wrapper bar={bar} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Foo = ({ bar }) => {
  return <div>{bar}</div>;
};

const Wrapper = ({ bar }) => {
  const [headerEl, setHeaderEl] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setHeaderEl(document.getElementById("header"));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Foo bar={bar} />
      {headerEl && ReactDOM.createPortal(<Foo bar={bar} />, headerEl)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: So you're saying to use `createPortal` but you're not recommending it?

Comment: @goto1 sometimes a solution is still valueable, even if it is not enterprise production ready

Comment: `createPortal` is certainly enterprise production ready

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.
"two places of the page" means two different DOM elements. different places in the memory.

either you use a parent state as suggested. or use two instances that talk to each other via messaging.

ReactDOM.createPortal will create one instance at the time as it takes the second argument as a single DOM element. https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html